# CSS selector to select element that has this id and this class

Tags: css, class, css-selectors

Can you select an element with CSS that has a certain id and a certain class?

Something like this I suppose:

```
#id.class {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: What's the gain? An id is already supposed to be unique?

Comment: @emboss: But an element with an ID isn't guaranteed to have a given class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say you have a `class` `people`. Their `background-color` is `white`. But if you refer to special people like `alice` or `bob`, you can use IDs to make them look special.

```
.people {
 background-color: white;
}

.people#alice {
 text-transform: capitalize;
}

.people#bob {
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

What are your intentions? If you want to have a generic people class and special alice and bob you could also use:

CSS:

```
.people {
 background-color: white;
}

#alice {
 text-transform: capitalize;
}

#bob {
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

and HTML:

```html
<div class="people" id="alice">Alice</div>
<div class="people" id="bob">Bob</div>
```

Comment: Are you saying that when you combine a class and id in a selector like you have, then a period does not precede the classname? I would think your selector would only be applied to `<people>` elements.

Comment: For anyone curious, order of selectors doesn't matter. `#id.class` and `.class#id` select exactly the same element.